# How to extract a tree from R memory?

Tags: r, phylogeny

I created a phylogenetic tree using "sim.bd.taxa.age". I just wanted to know how can I export the tree in newick format, given that currently it's not a phylo object!

```
library(TreeSim)
Tree <- sim.bd.taxa.age(n=300, numbsim=1, lambda=2, mu=0.5, frac = 1, age=250, mrca = FALSE)
```

Comment: library(TreeSim)                                                                                    Tree<-sim.bd.taxa.age(n=300, numbsim=1, lambda=2, mu=0.5, frac = 1, age=250, mrca = FALSE)

Comment: I want to get the "Tree" in newick format, somehow! While it's an object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the structure of `Tree`,

```
str(Tree)
List of 1
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ edge       : int [1:598, 1:2] 301 301 302 302 305 305 307 307 303 303 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:598] "" "" "" "" ...
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  ..$ tip.label  : chr [1:300] "t116" "t42" "t124" "t47" ...
  ..$ edge.length: num [1:598] 0.431 2.182 2.292 1.42 1.055 ...
  ..$ Nnode      : int 299
  ..$ root.edge  : num 245
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "phylo"
```

We see that it returns a list of length 1 with an element of class phylo. Presumably it returns a tree for each simulation you request (`numbsim`). To extract the tree, just do

```
Tree[[1]]
```

so you can write the three out with

```
write.tree(Tree[[1]], "newtreefile.txt")
```

which will write out in Newick format by default.